# Nokia N 950 installing QML app

Tags: qt, installation, nokia, qml, meego-harmattan

I am new to QT Quick app development.
I am working on an app to run over nokia symbian touoch devices like (c700 c601) and nokia meego devices like nokia n800 and nokia n950.

I was successful to install app on nokia symbian device c700. But when I try to install app on nokia n950 device it gives error that device not connected.
Also nokia ovi suit and nokia pc suit does not recognize device n950.
Could any one tell how would I install my app .sis file on nokia n950? Also does this device support installing .sis file or not?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the N950 uses Debian .deb packages. Details on how to do that are here
http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/guide/html/Developer_Library_Publishing_Packaging_your_application.html